# Bind image src from jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have a common .js file that used by all the controllers. When I bind the image src from jQuery, it is wotking for Home controllers. Remaining all controllers the path is bnot wotking.

My Code:

```
$(".staff-icon").attr("src", "Home/RetrieveStaffImage/" + r.sd.STAFF_IMAGE_ID);
```

Could you please suggest me the different options.

I have tried `URL.Action` and `Page.ResolveClientUrl` but no use.

Comment: Paste your html code, try use parent or child element to not override others

Comment: `@Url.Action` should definitely work. In your case, it should be: `"@Url.Action("RetrieveStaffImage", "Home")/' + r.sd.STAFF_IMAGE_ID`

Comment: I have used the below code..                                                                           
$(".staff-icon").attr("src", '@Url.Action("RetrieveStaffImage", "Home")/' + r.sd.STAFF_IMAGE_ID); but no use

Comment: This is not working when bind the src dynamically from jQuery..